# Ui-router adding path to end of existing path

Tags: angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router

I am making an oAuth site that people will land on starting at the path /core/login, and when I make state changes from that page all the urls are being appended to that. Ex. Reset Password has a state url of /core/resetPassword, but what is being displayed is /core/login/core/resetPassword.

What do I need to do to get ui router to append urls to the base url?

Answer (score 0):

Use "core" as a parent state and use "login" and "resetPassword" password as a child states.

```
.state('core', {
        url : '/core',
        abstract: true
})
.state('core.login', {
        url : 'login',
        templateUrl : 'fragments/login.html',
        controller : 'LoginController'
})
.state('core.resetPassword', {
        url : 'resetPassword',
        templateUrl : 'fragments/resetPassword.html',
        controller : 'ResetPasswordController'
})
```

Comment: That didn't do it. I'm still getting /core/login/core/resetPassword